# CakePHP deixar "action" e "template" mais conciso

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3, revisão-de-código

Eu tenho algumas perguntas sobre como eu posso melhorar esta "action" (método) em meu "controller":

> Pergunta discutida em: [Postar código funcional no stackoverflow visando uma refatoração?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4619/postar-c%C3%B3digo-funcional-no-stackoverflow-visando-uma-refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

1. Meu **template** tem uma barra de navegação com conteúdo dinâmico (se o usuário estiver "logado" um botão especial aparece, seu nome aparece na barra de navegação entre outras customizações) também a inserção dos "modais" é dinâmico, dependendo se o usuário está logado ou não, meu controlador chama alguns métodos que irá verificar se o usuário está "logado" e "setar" os dados para o template.
2. Eu estou inserindo o código que busca no banco de dados (Query Builder) diretamente na "action" (método) do controller.
3. Estou usando uma linha de comentário como esta "`//--------------------------`" para separar conceitos e operações. isto esta correto?
4. Eu estou usando um "Template" completo para cada "action" (método) (por exemplo: Um template completo para a action (método) `add` do controller `Products`(Nota: a maioria das páginas (adicionar, editar, apagar, índice) usam diferentes arquivos .js e .css).

**Controller:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class StoresController extends AppController
{
     public function miniMap()
    {
        $setting = [
            'fields' => ['id', 'banner_description', 'path_banner', 'url_redirect'],
            'conditions' => ['banner_type_id' => 2],
            'limit' => 1
        ];
        $fullBanners = TableRegistry::get('Banners')
            ->find('all', $setting)->hydrate(false)->toArray();
        $this->set('fullBanners', $fullBanners);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $setting = [
            'fields' => ['id', 'banner_description', 'path_banner', 'url_redirect'],
            'conditions' => ['banner_type_id' => 1],
            'limit' => 3
        ];
        $smallBanners = TableRegistry::get('Banners')
            ->find('all', $setting)->hydrate(false)->toArray();
        $this->set('smallBanners', $smallBanners);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $this->set('userId', $this->Auth->user('id'));

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $this->set('username', $this->Auth->user('username'));
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<?php    
    $this->layout = false;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('viewport','width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0') ?>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('title',$pageTitle) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico','/cart.png', ['type' => 'icon']) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('keywords','') ?>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('description','') ?>
        <?= $this->Html->meta('robots','index,follow') ?>

        <?= $this->Html->css('library/datepicker/css/datepicker.css') ?>
        <?= $this->Html->css('library/bxslider-4-4.1.2/jquery.bxslider.css') ?>
        <?= $this->Shrink->css(['styles/style.css', 'styles/menu-plugin.css']) ?>

        <?= $this->Html->script('library/bxslider-4-4.1.2/jquery.bxslider.min.js',['defer' => true]) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->script('actions/main.js',['defer' => true]) ?>

        <?= $this->Shrink->fetch('css') ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?= $this->element('Navbar/navbar_main') ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <?= $this->element('Body/categories') ?>
                    <?= $this->element('Body/stores') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $this->element('Footer/footer_information') ?>
        <?php if ($userId == false): ?>
            <?= $this->element('Modal/create_account_modal') ?>
            <?= $this->element('Modal/login_modal') ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?= $this->element('Modal/logout_modal') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```